# swiftui photopicker video is not accessible after rerunning the application

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, nsfilemanager, photo-picker

I'm trying to pick a video with photo picker this way:

```
@State var selectedItem: PhotosPickerItem? = nil
@State var showPhotoPicker = false
```

With those 2 states i'm showing the picker:

```
    .photosPicker(isPresented: $showPhotoPicker, selection: $selectedItem, matching: .videos)
    .onChange(of: selectedItem) {
        if let item = selectedItem {
            showProgress = true
            item.loadTransferable(type: SelectedMovie.self) { result in
                switch result {
                case .success(let movie):
                    if let movie = movie {
                        onVideoSelected(movie.url)
                    } else {
                        Log.w("movie is nil")
                    }
                case .failure(let failure):
                    Log.w("\(failure.localizedDescription)")
                }
                showProgress = false
            }
        }
    }
```

And my SelectedMovie is as follows:

```
struct SelectedMovie: Transferable {
let url: URL

static var transferRepresentation: some TransferRepresentation {
    FileRepresentation(contentType: .movie) { movie in
        SentTransferredFile(movie.url)
    } importing: { received in
        
        
        let fileName = received.file.lastPathComponent
        Log.d("File name: \(fileName)")
        let copy = URL.documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
        
        do {
            if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: copy.path()) {
                try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: copy)
            }
            
            try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: received.file, to: copy)
        } catch {
            Log.e("Cannot copy movie: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        
        Log.d("Copied: \(copy.path())")
        return Self.init(url: copy)
    }
  }
}
```

The path of my saved url is:

```
file:///Users/mymac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BB7B011B-B525-49E1-837E-4828D3151B3F/data/Containers/Data/Application/336F4FD2-F4EA-46E8-AB6B-80023E195E5E/Documents/mymovie.mp4
```

I'm using the Xcode simulator Iphone 15

I'm trying to save the selected video in the document directory, all goes well but when i'm rerunning the app (via xcode) the file is not accessible anymore.
any idea what i'm doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: The documents directory isn’t fixed, don’t save that. Only the file name and/or anything you append to the documents directory

Comment: @loremipsum
Thanks for responding, i'm already trying to append the file name to it. as you can see in my code. what am I doing wrong? appreciate for example.

Comment: I’m saying don’t  include the document directory in that URL the only thing that should be persisted is the part you append to the documents directory. You need to query FileManager each time for the document directory.

Comment: @loremipsum Thank you it worked, posted my code as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As lorem ipsum suggested (see comments in question),
I need to "play" only with my file name (lastPathComponent)
so my save logic is fine.

So instead of keeping the initial url (which holds non fixed path to the document folder)
I will take only its lastPathComponent and create the correct url:

```
let documentDir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
let url = dir.appendingPathComponent(initialUrl.lastPathComponent)
```

Alternatively,
I should save only the string of lastPathComponent instead the whole url but it will require db changes.

Thanks for assisting!